# explain the sub query working MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Writing a query to display the book code, book title ,supplier name and price of the book which takes maximum price based on each supplier.

I found the below query getting me right result but need explanations

```
select a.book_code,c.supplier_name,a.price from lms_book_details a 
  where a.price= (select max(price) from lms_book_details 
                   where supplier_id= a.supplier_id )
                  order by book_code;
  order by book_code;
```

Comment: Which explanations do you need?

Comment: This is called a correlated subquery. It's fine but it doesn't scale too well. Usually, an uncorrelated subquery performs better.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will fetch the row from `lms_book_details` with `maximum price`. If there more than one Row (record) with `maximum price` then it will return more than 1 and then **`order by book_code`**